# Double Series involving Gamma function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

Does anyone have any ideas on howto verify $$\sum_{n,m=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(n+m+3x)}{\Gamma(n+1+x)\Gamma(m+1+x)}\cdot \frac{1}{3^{n+m+3x-1}} = \Gamma(x)$$ for $x>0$?

I posted this question also on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2364283/double-series-equals-gamma-function).

This is not an exercise from a book, but arises due to my research in the study of a probability density.

Comment: LHS seems to have a pole at $x=-1/3$, while RHS does not.

Comment: (This is a problem because, contrary to Nemo, the series converges everywhere.)

Comment: This is equivalent to double integration $\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{u^{x-1} v^{x-1}}{(u+v+1)^{3 x}} dudv=\frac{\Gamma^3(x)}{3\Gamma(3x)}$.

Comment: This request is clearly much better suited to fit in math.SE. I feel very sorry, I should practice patience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can be reduced at least formally to a compact double integral, which might be easier to solve.

Starting with the integral representation for the Gamma function, we write the double sum as an integral of the square of the confluent hypergeometric function ${}_1F_1$, then apply analogue of Euler's transformation formula:
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n,m=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(n+m+3x)}{\Gamma(n+1+x)\Gamma(m+1+x)}\cdot \frac{1}{3^{n+m+3x-1}}\\
&=3\int_0^\infty e^{-3t}t^{3x-1}\sum_{n,m=0}^\infty \frac{t^{n+m}}{\Gamma(n+1+x)\Gamma(m+1+x)}dt\\
&=\frac3{\Gamma^2(x+1)}\int_0^\infty e^{-3t}t^{3x-1}~\left[{}_1F_1(1,x+1;t)\right]^2dt\\
&=\frac3{\Gamma^2(x+1)}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{3x-1}~\left[{}_1F_1(x,x+1;-t)\right]^2dt\\
&=\frac3{\Gamma^2(x+1)}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{3x-1}~\sum_{n,m=0}^\infty\frac{(x)_n(x)_m}{(x+1)_n(x+1)_m}\frac{(-t)^{n+m}}{n!m!}dt\\
&=\frac{3x^2}{\Gamma^2(x+1)}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{3x-1}~\sum_{n,m=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(x+n)(x+m)}\frac{(-t)^{n+m}}{n!m!}dt\\
&=\frac{3}{\Gamma^2(x)}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{3x-1}\int_0^1 du\int_0^1 dv\sum_{n,m=0}^\infty\frac{(-t)^{n+m}u^{n+x-1}v^{m+x-1}}{n!m!} dt\\
&=\frac{3}{\Gamma^2(x)}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{3x-1}\int_0^1 du\int_0^1 dv~ e^{-t(u+v)}(uv)^{x-1}dt\\
&=\frac{3\Gamma(3x)}{\Gamma^2(x)}\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{u^{x-1} v^{x-1}}{(u+v+1)^{3 x}} dudv.
\end{align}

This means that the initial problem is equivalent to
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{u^{x-1} v^{x-1}}{(u+v+1)^{3 x}} dudv=\frac{\Gamma^3(x)}{3\Gamma(3x)}.
$$

Comment: I didn't check any details of this answer, but for fun I had Mathematica spot-check if the double integral equals $\Gamma^3(x)/(3 \Gamma(3x))$.  For $x=1,2,3,4,5,6$, at least, Mathematica can verify both sides agree as rational numbers.  A couple other random non-integral choices of $x$ also gives agreement up to the default accuracy.

Comment: It is easy to prove that $\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \frac{u^{x-1} v^{x-1}}{(u+v+1)^{3 x}} dudv=\frac{\Gamma^3(x)}{\Gamma(3x)}$

Comment: There is a much simpler proof, just expand the function $\frac{1}{(3-(1-u)-(1-v))^{3x}}$ into the powers of $(1-u)^n(1-v)^m$ and integrate termwise.